# How to only get one vowel in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, append

I am having trouble getting the function to only print the vowel once if the string contains the vowel more than once. Here is the assignment:

Write Python function vowelList that takes one string parameter and compute and return the list of all
vowels in that string. Each vowel needs to be listed just once in the list and there should be no
distinction between lowercase and uppercase vowels. For example, the function call
vowelList(“mississippi”).
should return ['I'], since 'i' is the only vowel in the input string.

The output I need is:

```
['O']
```

The output I keep getting is:

```
['O', 'O']
```

This is what I have:

```
def vowelList(s):
    low = s.lower()
    L = []
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for char in low:
        if char not in L and char in vowels:
            L.append(char.upper())
    return L

print(vowelList("book"))
```

Comment: ```char```is in ```vowels``` but you end up uppercasing the ```O``` and you're comparing the ```char``` (lowercase) to the list of uppercase characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change

```
if char not in L and char in vowels:
```

to

```
if char in vowels and char.upper() not in L:
```

Here is the sample code:

```
def vowelList(s):
    low = s.lower()
    L = []
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for char in low:
        if char in vowels and char.upper() not in L:
            L.append(char.upper())
    return L

print(vowelList("book"))
```

Here is the sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You append uppercase letters to L but check if there are lowercase letters in it. Making the string an uppercase from the start would also be better.

```
up = s.upper()
L = []
vowels = "AEIOU"
for char in up:
    if char not in L and char in vowels:
        L.append(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set {} instead of a list, it makes the solution much prettier and theoretically and aesthetically appealing.